# how to set max legend width

Tags: legend

I have right aligned legend and I need to give it max width 25% of whole chart container. I've tried set width to 25% but in case when my series name is short legend box still stays as 25% but should be equal to content width. So I am looking for maxWidth property if it exist. I am in styled mode. Here is the the code     http://jsfiddle.net/sabira/xmcqjnvg/24/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
        styledMode: true,
    },
    legend: {
        align: 'right',
      layout: 'proximate',
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'very long long long long long name',
      data: [1, 4, 3, 5],
     },
    {
        name: 'short',
        data: [3, 5, 3, 1],
    }]
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `legend.maxWidth` property doesn't exist. However, it can be achieved by checking legend width in the chart load event and update it when it is bigger than eg. '25%' of the chart width.

**Code:**

```
  chart: {
    styledMode: true,
    events: {
      load: function() {
        var chart = this,
          legend = chart.legend,
          legendMaxWidth =
            Highcharts.relativeLength(legend.options.maxWidth, 1) * chart.chartWidth;

        if (legend.legendWidth > legendMaxWidth) {
          legend.update({
            width: legend.options.maxWidth
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fpwdtghk/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Legend#update

Answer (score 1):

For some one looking for an easier alternative to this just use itemWidth property of legend.

`legend:{ itemWidth: 100 }`

Updated Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/3mvpbu1f/